# Remove Boxy SVG from initial Ubuntu 20.04 set up

Tags: apt, .desktop

Does anyone know how to remove Boxy SVG from an initial Ubuntu set up? Both `sudo snap remove boxy-svg` and `sudo apt purge boxy-svg` fail.

[image]

Comment: Fail how?  Also how was it installed?  (to remove a package/program you use the opposite method to installation...)

Comment: It comes preinstalled with Ubuntu, which is why it fails with snap and apt: `snap "boxy-svg" is not installed` and `no apt package boxy-svg`

Comment: What is Boxy SVG? Where can we get it? How its main executable is named?

Comment: What are the results of `snap list | grep boxy-svg` ? If boxy-svg is installed it should appear in the results of `snap list | grep boxy-svg` in red letters. There is no apt package for boxy-svg in 20.04. If boxy-svg is not installed it should disappear after a reboot.

Comment: It's not installed in my Ubuntu system, and what I see in Ubuntu Software is *Proprietary Software* thus would not be installed by default, but is installed by users post-installation.

Comment: I didn't install it, it comes preinstalled in a full setup of Ubuntu 20.04. The icon shows in the launcher and it is not listed under `snap list`. It also does not show as installed in the Ubuntu Software center. If I install if from there, I get a separate copy with a duplicate launcher icon.

Comment: Please respond to the specific queries people are asking.

Comment: Do you mean https://snapcraft.io/boxy-svg ? What is the output of `which boxy-svg` ?

Comment: @N0rbert, Looks like it. `which boxy-svg` returns nothing, nor do `which boxy` or `which boxysvg`. I don't know what executable the launcher icon launches. It just sits there uselessly. @DK Bose, I answered all questions as far as I can tell.

Comment: Duh, it's actually a Chrome application where a launcher icon was placed when I synchronized Chrome with my profile!

Comment: @mrgou Please post last comment as answer to help other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be just a Chrome application. Chrome creates icons in the launcher. I just had to remove it from the Chrome applications at chrome://apps/

So if anyone ever sees an application they don't remember installing and can't get rid of, take a look there!